# Next JS and Vercel - development vs production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I’ve built a basic movie DB app in Next JS to see how the framework works. It’s an app that allows you to perform CRUD operations to firebase, utilising the NextJS API endpoints.

I have the app working fine in development, however it does not work at all once to Vercel. I was wondering if anyone can shed some light?

Here is the first 'get all data' call upon initialisation. The other API calls follow the same pattern. None work once deployed.

My index page has this getInitialProps function…

```
Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
    const categories = await getCategories()
    const movies = await getMovies()
    const images = movies.map(movie => {
      return {
        id: `image-${movie.id}`,
        url: movie.cover,
        name: movie.name
      }
    })
    
    return {
      movies,
      images,
      categories
    }
  }
```

This fires off the getMovies function here…

```
export const getMovies = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/movies')
    return res.data
```

And the API endpoint it hits looks like this…

```
import firebase from '../../lib/firebase';

export default async(req, res) => {
    const moviesRef = firebase
            .collection('movies');
            const snapshot = await moviesRef.get();
            const movies = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                movies.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
            })
            res.json(movies)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a requirement for you to use `getInitialProps` or could you use `getServerSideProps` instead?

Comment: Instead of making the axios API call, you should just import your code, like `import foo from './pages/api/movies'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't hardcode `http://localhost:3000` in the request's URL. You should omit it altogether since you're using Next.js API routes (same-origin).

```js
export const getMovies = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/movies')
    return res.data
}
```

**Edit:** The above solution would work with API routes if the request was happening on the *client-side* only.

Since the request is made in `getInitialProps`, you should simply move the logic in your API route to a separate function (could very well be `getMovies` in this case) and call that directly in `getInitialProps` instead.

```js
export const getMovies = async () => {
    const moviesRef = firebase.collection('movies');
    const snapshot = await moviesRef.get();
    const movies = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        movies.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
    });
    return movies;
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought the same coming from React, however the route only works if I explicitly type the entire route including localhost. If I omit localhost:3000, I get a server error. Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: Updated answer with a possible solution for `getInitialProps`.

Comment: Thanks Julio. I actually wanted to keep the function in the API routes for demonstration purposes however your suggestion is certainly the best way of doing it so I have marked it as a solution. As Andres suggested below, I only needed to change localhost:3000 to a dynamic server url and things worked using the API routes

Answer (score 2):

you should use your server link, not localhost.

Comment: How do I find/set my server link?

Comment: Check this, if you're using the API inside the Next JS project, you should call the backend with something like this (https://github.com/AndresCampuzano/Next.js-React-E-Commerce/blob/master/pages/index.tsx) I recommend you to upload your Next JS project to Vercel btw.

Comment: Thanks Andres, this worked and I have uploaded the project to Vercel